# Freeswitch callcenter Agent Auto answer not working

Tags: freeswitch

We are implementing the freeswitch with callcenter module.

We are not be able to set "Auto answer for the agents".

Please guide us if you have any idea ?

Auto answer is already set in the dial plan level but that is not working fine.